# Does the expression 'salad days' sound old-fashioned to a native speaker nowadays?

Tags: word-usage

I was fascinated when I first came across the phrase "salad days". I thought "in my salad days" sounded much more of a literacy style than the common expression "when I was young".

But when I tried to use this phrase in front of a native English speaker, he pointed out that it is an old-fashioned expression that hardly anyone uses nowadays. I sought verification from another native speaker and he simply said that he had never heard of it, not to mention using it.

Then I looked up "salad days" in the dictionaries and LDOCE (Longman) tags it "old-fashioned" while M-W says it is "somewhat old-fashioned".

Finally I fell back on English Corpus and found "salad days" actually was still in use in newspapers and magazines, for example.

> *The numbers provided further evidence that Netflix’s salad days may be over, particularly in the U.S., where most households that want its
> 12-year-old streaming service already have it. — Washington Post,
> "Netflix’s US subscriber growth slowing as competition looms," 16 Oct.
> 2019*

> *Back during the salad days of their relationship, Ms. Cooper and Mr. Weah traveled together to Monte Carlo and Mexico. — Helene Cooper, New
> York Times, "Liberia Holds a Free Election. Make That
> ‘Free-for-All.’," 6 Oct. 2017*

I also checked youtube videos and found that "salad days" is also used by some of young youtubers as well as some celebrities in their spoken English in a talkshow.

Does *salad days* fit the definition of an old-fashioned word or expression?

Comment: I think this is very much a matter of opinion. You will likely get a range of reactions to expressions like "salad days": understanding, amusement, confusion, etc. depending on an individual listener's age and background.

Comment: I've boiled the questions originally asked down to one reasonably objective question, which invites a definition of what makes an expression old-fashioned. It's still a bit subjective, but it's probably [good subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: The expression actually comes from Shakespeare's _Antony and Cleopatra_. There was a musical of that name in the 1950s which no doubt helped to popularise the phrase, but it's largely been forgotten again and you hardly ever hear it in ordinary conversation.

Comment: I agree with Kate Bunting above: To me, it also carries a nuance of the person being happy, without worries, and innocently unconcerned by what they did/do. If the examples in the OED are a guide, there was little use of the phrase from Shakespeare until the mid-19th century. It seems to be more used in written English than spoken - as you remark, it has a literary style.

Comment: It is rare in everyday conversation, a little more common in the media say, and quite unremarkable (ie no raising of eyebrows / friend 'point[ing] out that it is an old-fashioned expression that hardly anyone uses nowadays') in literature, especially British Victorian / Edwardian.

Comment: How is this opinion based? Do a Google ngrams graph.

Comment: @Mitch It's opinion-based because it asks whether it "sounds" old-fashioned to "a native speaker," which is impossible to know. How prevalent it might be in print is a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

Just addressing the expression “salad days”, I would say that (despite the dictionaries) its limited contemporary use reflects that fact that it is more a *literary or poetic* metaphor than *old-fashioned* usage.

As all educated people once (and there‘s the rub†) knew, the expression comes from Shakespeare’s *Anthony and Cleopatra*:

> *My salad days,*
> *When I was green in judgement, cold in blood,*
> *To say as I said then!*

The fact that it was reused as the title of a [musical in the 1950s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salad_Days_(musical)) suggests a certain exotic feel to the expression, rather than it being a common synonym for “youth”. To be old-fashioned an expression must have been popular at one time, and I remain to be convinced that this is the case. — *I do not ever recall hearing it in conversation.* Ordinary people avoid using literary expressions in popular speech, and educated people would tend to avoid bathetic use. Journalists, however, as the quotations in the question attest, were and are different.

The [Google books ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=salad+days&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) shows little use of the expression before about 1840, hitting a peak of popularity at about 1900. Its overall use has remained steady since then, with a recent increase in the US. However the late 20th and early 21st century hits in the ngram  to some extent reflect the numerous cookery books and articles using this as catchy/glib title. I imagine many young people today are unaware of the literary illusion, although the novelists and biographers continue to recycle it.

In conclusion, “salad days” would seem to be no less “in fashion” than a hundred years ago. Its relatively limited usage — which has not changed much — would seem to reflect its literary nature and, in this respect, its lack of originality.

†An old-fashioned literary expression (Don’t try it at home.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
You mentioned, "Journalists, however, were and are different." I wonder why journalists more tend to use the such words? What kind of style of language do they usually pursue in their articles while others may try to avoid?

Comment: @Pedant — My remark was meant ironically. But journalists have other things to consider besides literary style. They have to attract and hold the attention of the reader, so they often use colourful expressions to do this. And if it’s a bit hackneyed, never mind, they have a deadline to meet and the day after it’s published everyone will have forgotten.

Comment: @David - _"I do not ever recall hearing it in conversation."_ - a solicitor and part-time County Court judge told me the other week that he drove a Mini Cooper "in his salad days", which we both understood to be the early 1970s.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey — As with the Mini Cooper, your mileage may vary.

Comment: He's a nice old boy, (same age as me) and now he's got an electric bicycle.